# Using Kentor + Windows Authentication on IdentityServer3

Tags: c#, windows-authentication, saml-2.0, identityserver3, kentor-authservices

I have an IdentityServer3 working with [Windows Authentication Service](https://github.com/IdentityServer/WindowsAuthentication). Now I want to handle the SAML2 protocol on my IdentityServer3 and I saw [Kentor](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices) could do it for me.

The problem is that Kentor is using OpenID Connect in all samples, I searched a while but i couldn't find any documentation on how to combine Kentor with WindowsAuth. After many tries without success, I come here to ask if it is realy possible and how ?

**Here is my (non-working) configuration in Startup.cs :**

```cs
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    appBuilder.Map("/windows", ConfigureWindowsTokenProvider);
    appBuilder.UseIdentityServer(GetIdentityServerOptions());
}

private void ConfigureWsFederation(IAppBuilder pluginApp, IdentityServerOptions options)
{
    var factory = new WsFederationServiceFactory(options.Factory);

    factory.Register(new Registration<IEnumerable<RelyingParty>>(RelyingParties.Get()));
    factory.RelyingPartyService = new Registration<IRelyingPartyService>(typeof(InMemoryRelyingPartyService));
    factory.CustomClaimsService = new Registration<ICustomWsFederationClaimsService>(typeof(ClaimsService));
    factory.CustomRequestValidator = new Registration<ICustomWsFederationRequestValidator>(typeof(RequestValidator));

    var wsFedOptions = new WsFederationPluginOptions
    {
        IdentityServerOptions = options,
        Factory = factory,
    };

    pluginApp.UseWsFederationPlugin(wsFedOptions);
}

private IdentityServerOptions GetIdentityServerOptions()
{
    DefaultViewServiceOptions viewServiceOptions = new DefaultViewServiceOptions();
    viewServiceOptions.CustomViewDirectory = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Templates");
    viewServiceOptions.Stylesheets.Add("/Content/Custom.css");

    IdentityServerServiceFactory factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
        .UseInMemoryClients(new List<Client>())
        .UseInMemoryScopes(new List<Scope>());

    factory.ConfigureDefaultViewService(viewServiceOptions);
    factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(resolver => new UserService());

    return new IdentityServerOptions
    {
        SigningCertificate = Certificate.Load(),
        Factory = factory,
        PluginConfiguration = ConfigureWsFederation,
        EventsOptions = new EventsOptions
        {
            RaiseSuccessEvents = true,
            RaiseFailureEvents = true,
        },
        AuthenticationOptions = new IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.AuthenticationOptions
        {
            IdentityProviders = ConfigureIdentityProviders,
            EnableLocalLogin = false,
        },
        RequireSsl = true,
    };
}

private void ConfigureIdentityProviders(IAppBuilder app, string signInAsType)
{
    ConfigureWSFederationProvider(app, signInAsType);
    ConfigureKentorProvider(app, signInAsType);
}

private void ConfigureKentorProvider(IAppBuilder app, string signInAsType)
{
    SPOptions spOptions = new SPOptions
    {
        EntityId = new EntityId("Dropbox"),
    };
    KentorAuthServicesAuthenticationOptions kentorOptions = new KentorAuthServicesAuthenticationOptions(false)
    {
        Caption = "Windows",
        SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,
        SPOptions = spOptions,
    };
    IdentityProvider idp = new IdentityProvider(new EntityId("http://stubidp.kentor.se/Metadata"), spOptions)
    {
        Binding = Saml2BindingType.HttpRedirect,
        AllowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse = true,
        LoadMetadata = true,
    };
    kentorOptions.IdentityProviders.Add(idp);
    app.UseKentorAuthServicesAuthentication(kentorOptions);
}

private void ConfigureWSFederationProvider(IAppBuilder app, string signInAsType)
{
    app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        AuthenticationType = "windows",
        Caption = "Windows",
        SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,

        MetadataAddress = serverHost + "windows",
        Wtrealm = "urn:idsrv3",
    });
}

private void ConfigureWindowsTokenProvider(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseWindowsAuthenticationService(new WindowsAuthenticationOptions
    {
        IdpReplyUrl = serverHost,
        SigningCertificate = Certificate.Load(),
        EnableOAuth2Endpoint = false,
    });
}
```

This configuration builds, but when I use the Dropbox SSO (using SAML2) I get the exception `No Idp with entity id "Dropbox" found`.

Comment: `Caption = "Windows",` looks wrong in your Kentor code, but sounds like your main issues are elsewhere.

Comment: And yes, it's possible to use both Kentor.AuthServices and Windows as separate external identity providers within IdentityServer3. I don't have time to distill my current code into a smaller sample but I started with https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/tree/master/SampleIdentityServer3 and then added in the Windows auth sample from IdentityServer3

Comment: thanks for you comment, but I need to make them work together, not separatly. That's the point of my post.

Comment: Sorry, "separate" was maybe the wrong word. I mean have a setup where there are "log in with Windows" and "log in with XYZ SAML" buttons on the same login page. Is that your goal also? Or what did you mean by having them work together?

Comment: My final goal is to authenticate users from dropbox (and other SP using SAML2) with windows authentication, I thought Kentor could do it.

Answer (score 0):

You've configured "Dropbox" as the identity (EntityId in SAML2 terms) of *your application* (the one in SpOptions). That should be a URI that identifies your application. The convention is to use the URL to the metadata (~/AuthServices).

You need to add an IdentityProvider with the settings of the dropbox idp. Please also note that an EntityId of "Dropbox" won't work as the SAML2 standard requires an Entity ID to be an absolute URI.